# search printf statement in file and replace with string value

Tags: c++, stringstream, dev-c++

I am trying to replace all `printf` statements with a string value. So first, I am reading all lines to a string as below:

```
 ifstream ifs;
 ifs.open(filename);
 string temp;
 string text;
 while(!ifs.eof())
 {
     getline(ifs, temp, '\t');
     text.append(temp);
     temp.clear();
 }
```

Then I'm finding every line for `printf` and if it founds, than replacing it with a `"printf statement"`.
 **My code for replacing `printf` :**

```
char ch;
while(getline(is,check))
{
 ch=check[0];
    if(!isalpha(ch))
     {
      //statements..
     }
    else
     {
        string str2("printf");
        size_t found;
        found=check.find(str2);
           if(found!=string::npos)
              check="\n printf statement.\n";
       OriginalStr.append(check);

         check.clear();
     }
```

It's working for three four line files like below:

```
main()
{
Hi i am Adityaram.
and i am good boy.
and you?
printf("");
{
printf("");
Aditya
printf("");
Rammm
printf("");
Kumar
printf("");
{
printf("");

printf("");
}
printf("");
}
printf("");
```

but not finding printf line in these lines of file.

```
main()
{
   char ch, file_name[25],*p;
   char answer[400];
   int size=0;
   FILE *fp;

   printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see ");
   gets(file_name);
}
```

Why it is not finding printf line? or how to do?
any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to declare all your variables at the beginning of the function. Don't do that in C++, it just destroys readability of your code.

Comment: Lines could be empty. You never check that and then when you do `ch=check[0];` you're invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: Languages such as Perl are much better suited to this kind of task. If you don't know at least one language with built in reg ex support etc then do yourself a favour and learn one.

Comment: `eof` is almost always, and certainly in your case, wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a C program, you might have lines as:

```
{
```

or

```
}
```

ie. opening/closing a block. This is definitely not empty, but it will contain only 1 character. In your `while i<6`you are going way after the end of this buffer. So, add there a check that `i` is less than the length of the buffer.

Then it might happen that printf is not necessarily the first expression in the line, such as:

```
if(something) printf("this");
```

Your code is not picking this up. You will need to check for the "printf" as a substring in your `wd`. Look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/ for reference on finding strings in a string.

And last but not least, I don't see why you want your line to start with a letter (the check for isalpha). This will fail to change code like

```
{ printf("this"); }
```

And the reason that it works for small test files is because highly possibly you wrote them to pass your internal "test" but large files usually contain more widely used printf's.

Also, it is not mandatory that the indentation happens with tabs (\t) it might be simple spaces.

Comment: how to do for large files than.

Answer (score 0):

i got it, by this simple way:

```
string RemovePrintf(string value)
{
     string RemovedPrintf,strP;
     size_t poss;
     value.insert(0," ");//insert a white-space, cause  find method not returning position if it present at begin of string.
     poss = value.find("printf");    // position of "printf" in str
     strP = ""; // get insert whitespace at "printf line".
     strP.resize(strP.length());
     if((int)poss > 0)
      RemovedPrintf.append(strP);
     else
      RemovedPrintf.append(value);
     strP.clear();
     RemovedPrintf.resize(RemovedPrintf.length());
     return RemovedPrintf;
}
```

This works for both small files and large too.
By the way thanks for responding my question.